Wife missing in Italy
My wife arrived today in Palermo at the airport, since then I have no news, she hasn't checked into her hotel and her phone is off in the icloud find my phone feature. I haven't had news since yesterday night when she was transiting in Istanbul. I am not in Italy, I called the Italian police in Palermo and they could not help me. What can I do to find her? We had not argued and she usually calls me as soon as she arrives somewhere. I'm very worried something bad happened to her. What can I do?
Edit: I found her all ends well, she met some compatriots on the plane and they drove in a rented car without sim cards. Thanks for the help!

You should reach out to government agencies. Best approach would be to reach out to your embassy who can guide you with next steps

To expand on Travelling Juggernaut's comment: If your wife is a citizen of Country X, contact the Embassy of Country X in Italy. If Country X maintains a Consulate in Sicily (if it does, it's probably in Palermo), contact that Consulate.

Where did she start her journey? If it was from her home country,  does she have relatives there whom you could contact to ask if they have heard from her? Was she travelling alone, did you see her off at the airport when she left to travel to Palermo?

Do you know for sure she was onboard the flight from Istanbul to Palermo? What is her citizenship? Is there any possibly she was refused boarding or refused entry into Italy? Do you have access to her booking?

If the iPhone is new enough, it should broadcast a location even if turned off or without coverage (unless the feature was disabled of course). That is very weird that there is no location.

@jcaron Hello I called the airline they said she was onboard.

@NicolasFormichella Maybe it's because i'm checking online, I don't have an iphone and anyways there is 2fa except for my browser which connected.

The phone might have problems, be broken or even stolen. It is not a given she has problems herself.

I found her thanks a lot guys.

@willeke all is ok I overeacted, I found her.

Been there, done that.

@Worriedtemp1991, that is what we hoped for.

@Worriedtemp1991 I wouldn't call it an overreaction - it can be so hard when you're in another part of the world.  Been there, done that!  Glad to hear she's OK

The SIM card thing sounds like the overreaction. People flying across the globe, but scared to hell about sending an SMS on roaming tariff. Also, WiFi exists.

I'm sorry, that is a difficult situation. Here are a few things you can try:

Contact your embassy or the closest consulate in Italy. Here is a list of consulates in Palermo: https://embassies.net/italy/palermo
Check with the airline to verify that she was indeed on board and that her luggage was picked up. Airlines may not give you this info (for privacy reasons), but you can hang up and try again or ask for an supervisor.
If you know your wife's itinerary, check with the hotel or place(s) where she was planning to stay.
I assume that your wife went to Palermo for a reason. If she was going for work, meet with someone, take a tour, etc, try to contact any person who may know about this.
Call the major hospitals and ask for any recently admitted patients that are either your wife or unidentified.
Try the police again. You may find someone who is more willing to engage.


It may also be worthwhile to try the police in your home town or city; if they are willing to investigate, they might be able to get more information out of the police in the place where she had planned to travel.  It may be too soon at this point, but eventually it will no longer be too soon.

Thanks a lot, I found her she was with friends and they didn't have sim cards yet.
